# PYTHON in MAYA : listAttr with uiTypes

Tags: python, maya

I would like to know if there is a way to list all attributes of an UI object like when we execute `pymel.core.listAttr(node)`.

Answer (score 1):

UI objects don't have attributes like conventional DAG nodes: they have to be queried with commands, rather than having properties that can be accessed directly.

[This blog post](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/02/rescuing-maya-gui-from-itself.html) and its [followup](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/03/maya-gui-ii-all-your-base-classes-are.html) discuss how you can uses Python wrapper classes to make it *look* like gui items have properties (ie `window1.width = 100` rather than `cmds.window('window1', e=True, w=100)`.

The articles refer to an open source [maya gui library that works exactly like that](https://github.com/theodox/mGui)